# jQuery issue ($ is not a function) only on live server

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm getting the following jQuery errors on my WordPress website:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $_GET is not defined

However, I only have this issue on my hosted server, and not on localhost, (although the code is pretty much the same aside of wp-config).

Thus I cannot use the solutions provided for those errors because I'm not encountering them on my local server. Not sure how to proceed!

Comment: Can you add some code?. it looks you are using $_GET without php tags or you are using $_GET in js file

Comment: $_GET is actually also a javascript function in that case (don't ask me why, not my code). I removed that part but am I still encountering the same issue.

One weird thing : as I upload my files to my server, the formatting seems to change and some js files actually end up smaller than the original source. 

I am now getting : 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`
Although the js file is fine and works perfectly locally.

Comment: I can sure help you out if you post some code of that part?.
Like above and below 5 lines of that code ?.

Comment: Show the code and also name the file and i will help you out

Comment: I am unsure which part of code could give you a hint. Here's a piece where I get an error :

`
`$( "#sliderPrice" ).slider({

` });

It looks like I have an issue with uploading the files. I reuploaded manually the js file that had errors, and I suddenly have fewer of them. "Unexpected token" is gone and I am now only getting errors such as :

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function`

Comment: Try using `jQuery('#sliderPrice').slider();`

Comment: I am now getting :

`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function`

Comment: Have you enqueued the slider script ?

Comment: Can you share your url ?so i can see properly?

Comment: Ok, remove it now

Comment: I also have the same issue with jQuery's autocomplete, although this one is queued. And I still don't understand why these errors would only appear on my remote server, and not on localhost

Comment: Here the problem is that jQuery says that `.slider()` an `.autocomplete()` are not a valid function.  You need to make sure that any of the scripts that are defining these function should be placed above the `functions.js` (which is the file from where these functions are called)

Comment: Is there a config file that I can modify to ensure that functions.js is loaded before the others ? I am kind of lost between the several wp_enqueue_script(). And again, do you know why it would work on localhost and not on a remote server ?

Comment: I don't know why but may be due to strict mode or something. 
You need to decrease the priority of parent function of wp_enqueue_script. 
These can be done by adding a 3rd parameter in add_action. 
So it would be `add_action('your_action_name','your_function_name',99)`

Comment: Good idea actually, I'll try that out, thanks

Comment: I doubt it's a script loading issue actually. I now get :
`$ is not a function`

at core.js, index.php...

Comment: it seems to be at same place.

Comment: I am currently trying a few things. What I don't understand is that autocomplete, slider (not a plugin, got confused) or even datepicker are native jQuery UI functions and those should work if jQuery UI is loaded.
  

Thus I assume that this is a jQuery UI loading issue, however the whole code is in $(document).ready() loop and for some reason it works on localhost.

Comment: jQueryUi is not loaded at all. if you see the source code you can see that jqueryui is commented out. and also is loaded after functions.js . So what you need to do is comment out UI code and enqueue it before functions.js

Comment: It should now be loaded and queued properly. I don't have any errors left, however nothing shows up on the page. I am unsure what to do next !

Comment: Okay, I found the issue. It was a PHP function trying to create a temp folder without having the required permissions, thus throwing an error and preventing some parts of the page from loading properly.

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress you cannot use `$` for jQuery operations, you need to replace that to `jQuery`.

About the `$_GET`, you are probably not using the PHP code the proper way.
Please post some code to check it out.

Comment: I'm already replacing $ with jquery in the code, and I think that I would get errors on localhost as well if this was the issue.

Comment: it is 'jQuery', though it can be used with wrapping a function as `$` . Also if you see properly he has used $_GET which is php

Comment: I've edited my answer to the proper value for `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use a jQuery's `noConflict()` function - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

It was working for me sometimes when I had similar problems.